# Best practices to copy a large number of very big databases with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, replication

I have been tasked with getting a copy of our SQL Server 2005/2008 databases in the field on-line internally and update them daily. Connectivity with each site is regulated, so on-line access is not an option. Field databases are Workgroup licensed. Main server is Enterprise with some obscene number of processors and RAM. The purpose of the copies is two-fold: (1) on-line backup and (2) source for ETL to the data warehouse.

There are about 300 databases, identical schema for the most part, located throughout the US, Canada and Mexico. Current DB size is between 5 GB and over 1 TB. Activity varies, but is about a 1,500,000 new rows daily on each server, mostly in 2 tables. About 50 tables total in each. Connection quality and bandwidth with each site varies, but the main site has enough bandwidth to do many sites in parallel.

I'm thinking SSIS, but am not sure how to approach this task other than table-by-table. Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: How will you be able to identify changes?

Comment: The rows are identified with sequential bigint. I get the max id from the local db for the site and get everything with a higher id from the remote. Standard SSIS on the smaller tables. -  select id from remote_table where id is not in (select id from local_table) -- to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would recommend using SQL replication. We do this quite a bit, and it will even work over dialup. It basically minimizes traffic needed as only changes are transferred.

There are several topologies. We only use merge (two way), but transactional might be OK for your needs (one way).

Our environments are a single central DB, replicating (using filtered replication articles) to various site databases. The central DB is the publisher. It is robust, once in place, but is a nuisance for schema upgrades.

However, given your databases aren't homogeneous, it might be easier to set it up where the remote site is the publisher, and the central SQL instance has a per site database that is a subscriber to the site publisher. The articles wouldn't even need to be filtered. And then you can process the individual site data centrally.

Note to have the site databases would need replication components installed (they are generally optional in the installer). To be setup as publishers they'd need local configuration also (distribution configured on each one). Being workgroup edition, it can act as a publisher. SQL express can't act as a publisher.

It sounds complicated, but it is really just procedural, and an inbuilt mechanism for doing this sort of thing.